# Detect position of node in document using XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq

I use the following LINQ request to parse XML file:

```
var names = from student in XDocument.Load(pwd, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo).Descendants(rootSection)

    Elements(rootNodeAttribute.Text)
    .Where(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == textBox2.Text).Elements(nodeValue).Elements("alt")
    let lineInfo = (IXmlLineInfo)student
     select new
     {
      ID = count++,
      Name = student.Value,
      Ref = student.Attribute("ref") != null ? student.Attribute("ref").Value : ""
    };
```

It works fine.

How to define position elements that were found in `select new`?
I want to bind position of each element to datagrid cell, that after I can update these nodes elements.